# Passing ByteArray from C# function to Lua code

Tags: c#, lua, arrays

I work on a C# based GUI interfacing with a Lua engine. I searched for help but I am not getting a correct solution and I cannot change much on the Lua side because the LuaInterface.dll is given to me and cannot be changed.

In C#, I have a function as below:

```
public Int32 Calculate_Func(string input,out Byte[] byte_arr)
{
  byte_arr = Process(input);
  return 1;
}
```

In Lua, I call the above function as:

```
ret, val = Calculate_Func(Packet_String)
```

But I see that the byte array is not getting reflected in my Lua function. When I try reading the value of the `val` variable, it returns `System.Byte[]`. I am unable to access the byte array values in Lua.

But If I change the byte array to string, the value gets returned, but I need the bytes to be processed in Lua. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It seems like your marshalling library can't convert `System.Byte[]` to LUA buffer and it's transferred to LUA as userdata. You can try to convert to some different type like `char[]`, for example - may be `LuaInterface.dll` familiar with it.
It would be convenient to examine exports of `LuaInterface.dll` - as far as I understand, it must export functions used to marshal types back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Int32 Calculate_Func(string input, out LuaTable byte_arr)
{
    byte[] arr = Process(input);
    byte_arr = (LuaTable)lua.DoString("return {"+String.Join(",", byte_arr)+"}");
    return 1;
}
```